# Does Service stop itself automatically after onStartCommand() done?

Tags: android, service

When I call `this.startService(new Intent(this, Some_Service.class));`
I know that `onCreate()` is called and followed by `onStartCommand()`.

Bur what happens if the code in `onStartCommand()` done?.
Does `Service` automatically call `onDestroy()` to stop itself?
Or do I must call `this.stopService(new Intent(this, Some_Service.class));` to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start a service by calling `startService()` then you have to call `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` to stop the service. If you want to stop a service after doing some work, you might want to use `IntentService` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`onStartCommand()` -
The system calls this method when another component, such as an activity, requests that the service be started, by calling `startService()`. Once this method executes, the service is started and can run in the background indefinitely. If you implement this, it is your responsibility to stop the service when its work is done, by calling `stopSelf()` or `stopService()`. (If you only want to provide binding, you don't need to implement this method.)

[Read Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)