# app forceclose while running in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, forceclose, background-service

In my android app i have one service which calls some webservices after a fix interval.
App is running perfectly in foreground and refresh data,but when user exit from app and use some other app then my app force close after many times.
Why this app force close while running in background.

Code that i was using for start service -

```
    msgIntent = new Intent(mContext, MyBackgroundService.class);
    startService(msgIntent);
```

and inside onDestroy() of my main activity i have following code to stop service-

```
        if(msgIntent!=null){
            stopService(msgIntent);
        }
```

background service call some async task and each aync task onPostExecute() method execute some insert statement in database.

i am not geting why this force close occure.

Please give your comments.

Thanks in advance.

**My Service Code**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    callAsynchronousTask();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mContext = this;
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


   public void callAsynchronousTask() {
     final Handler handler = new Handler();
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
      @Override
     public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {       
                try {
                    callWebservice();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, START_DELAY, DELAY);
}
```

Comment: stack trace please !!

Comment: @rb16 post the logcat logs

Comment: Post code of service & logcat as well

Comment: i am not getting any log because it was force close when app is not running and not connected to usb.

Comment: @RIT i am not able to add logcat because app force close when other app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is here

```
    if(msgIntent!=null){
        stopService(msgIntent);
    }
```

in your `onDestroy(`). Because when you close your application so this above code gets called which is closing your service.
And after closing service again you are trying to insert data by calling service + web service. Hence, there is no service object thats why it gets crashed.

To handle this scenario, you need to comment above code which is in `onDestroy()` & then check/run it, will solve your problem. & there you need to stop your service by other ways. Go step by step.

Answer (score 0):

you stop the service at **onDestroy()** method. but services are not depend the activity. So try to neglect the stop service.
(or)

```
try
{
//stop service code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

try this.

Comment: so how can i force stop service when app is not running

Comment: service used for frequent running programms, Example notification msg check online(whatsapp).

Comment: i dont want to run service while app is not running

Comment: check this two link for stop service itself. [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905870/does-service-stop-itself-automatically-after-onstartcommand-done), [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886874/how-to-stop-service-by-itself)